# How to get the value of a table row and use it in an else if statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm not good with selecting info from databases.

I want a different header for buyers and sellers. I have a check to see if they're logged in but don't know how to get the code to look into the database and tell if they are logged in as a buyer or seller.

This is what I have:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) == 1 && (check if usertype is buyer and maybe put this into a variable)) { include('header_buyer.php');

}

else (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) == 1 && (check if usertype is seller)) { include('header_seller.php'); 

}
```

I don't know how to check from my table 'users' from usertype if they are buyer or seller  and maybe put this into a variable so it can be written as

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) == 1 && ($usertype == 'buyer')) { include('header_buyer.php');
```

...or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

select your user from data base then log user type in session

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die ("Can't connect to database server");
mysql_select_db("yourDb") or die ("Can't select database");
$query = mysql_query('select user_id, user_type from user user_id = 2');

$resutl = mysql_fetch_array($query);

if ($resutl) {
    $_SESSION['user_type'] = $resutl['user_type'];
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest...

```
// connect to the database
mysql_connect('localhost','username','password') or die ('Can\'t connect to the database');
mysql_select_db('yourDatabase') or die ('Can\'t select database table');

// check the session to see if they are logged in or not
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {

    // we know the user is logged in, so query the database work out what type they are
    $query = mysql_query('SELECT `userType` FROM `yourTable` WHERE `id` = theirID LIMIT 1;')

    // extract the data from the result
    $userType = mysql_result($query,0,0); // row 0, column 0 of the return data

    // include the file you need
    if ($userType=='buyer') {
        include('header_buyer.php');
    } elseif ($userType=='seller') {
        include('header_seller.php');
    } else {
        // handle an invalid user type
    }

} else {

    // they are not logged in

}
```

Of course you'd need to change the database fields, and include their ID from wherever it is stored (if it isn't stored, you can store it inside a session during the login process).